# How do I convert a sequence file to parquet format

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark, presto

I have a HIVE Table **(test)** that I need to create in the *PARQUET* format. I will be using a bunch of *SEQUENCE* files in order to create and insert into a table.

Once the table is created, is there a way to convert into PARQUET? I mean I know we could have done, say

```
CREATE TABLE default.test( user_id STRING, location STRING) 
PARTITIONED BY ( dt INT ) STORED AS PARQUET
```

initially while creating the table itself. However, in my  case I am forced to use SEQUENCE files to create the table first because it is the format that I have to begin with and cannot directly convert to PARQUET.
Is there a way I could convert into parquet after the table is created and data inserted?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I made some edits to my question. Hope it makes it a little better to understand now.

Comment: Few clarifications, 
* Would you like to have this process of conversion done in native Hive or using PySpark
* If Hive/PySpark have you tried anything yet from your end, where you are facing issues and unable to proceed

If you can provide us with some sample code of what you have tried so far or stuck at some point with issues then can you please have them also included into the question.

Comment: Thank you for asking. I would like to eventually use this Parquet table in the Presto environment. The question is, should I use the strategy suggested below(by Piotr Findeisen) or convert the file to Parquet manually first before loading it into Presto. I am open to using PySpark to convert it manually. Not sure how I would go about doing that, never used PySpark before.

Answer (score 0):

To convert form sequence file to Parquet you need to load the data (CTAS) into a new table.

The question is tagged with `presto`, so I am giving you [Presto syntax](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#examples) for this. I am including partitioning, because example in the question contains it.

```
CREATE TABLE test_parquet WITH(format='PARQUET', partitioned_by=ARRAY['dt']) AS
SELECT * FROM test_sequencefile;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You're right I am going to use this table in a Presto environment. Is this the round about way(first create table in presto using SEQ files and then CTAS as PARQUET) the only way to solve my problem?

Comment: You are writing Sequence files to HDFS/S3. And then you want to rewrite them into Parquet. There is no "in place" solution in Presto or Hive that I know of. This is the simplest I can think of.

Comment: Thank you.  @piotr - how do I account for daily incremental files(new SEQ files) and append that to the existing table. Do I have to rebuild the entire table and then convert to parquet?

Comment: I'd consider converting to Parquet within ingestion pipeline. Anyway, l invite you to join Presto Community Slack (https://prestosql.io/slack.html), where you can get advice from other community members as well.